# How to integrate Google map location in website either in java script or php?

Tags: php

I have pointed my location in google map using mapmaker.My company name is VK Academy It solutions.my question is how do i point to my website..... I want to know how to do in java script and php

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Google's own map embedding? https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

See this example.i think this is useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;
key=ABQIA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadEarth(mapdiv) {
   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
      var point;
      if(!mapdiv)return true;
      var map=new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
      map.enableDoubleClickZoom();
      map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
      map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
      map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
      var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(37.4419,-122.1419));
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419,-122.1419),17);
      GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("hii");});
      map.addOverlay(marker);
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 16);
      map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
      var polyline = new GPolyline([new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519),
    new GLatLng( 37.4619, -122.1819)], "#3333cc", 10);
      }
      map.addOverlay(polyline);
 }
    </script>
</head>
 <body onload="loadEarth('map')" onunload="GUnload()" style=" 
                background-color:Transparent">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**if above code is not useful..go to below link.**
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20590/Google-Maps-in-HTML-ASP-NET-PHP-JSP-etc-with-ease

Comment: first search in google.many blogs are available for this type of questions